# Python: List Comprehensions con operador or?

Tags: python

Muy buenas

Tenia un problema para definir una List Comprehensions. Quería extraer los datos de una lista y sus indices. En un principio hice esto:

```
Lista2 = [Indices.append(indices) Carac.append(carac) for indices,carac in enumerate(Lista1)]
```

Pero esto me daba error, ya que no me dejaba declarar las 2 expresiones:

```
Indices.append(indices) Carac.append(carac)
```

Conseguí solucionarlo intercalando las 2 expresiones con un "**or**" y funciono.

```
Lista2 = [Indices.append(indices)  or  Carac.append(carac) for indices,carac in enumerate(Unicode)]
```

Pero no entiendo porque y no se que función cumple el or, aunque como ya digo...funciona a la perfección. Obtengo una lista con los elementos y otra con sus indices. Alguien podría explicarme que función cumple el "or" y porque es que funciona ??

Comment: `or` regresa el primer valor "verdadero" ó el segundo valor si ambos son "falsos". `Lista2` contiene esos valores que regresa el `or`. Lista2 contiene valores de tipo `NoneTyepe`.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo estás haciendo un uso equivocado y que además es muy ineficiente de las listas por compresión. Las listas por compresión no son una forma de "acelerar" un ciclo `for` como puede pensarse, son (explicado de forma genérica) una forma simplificada y reducida de crear listas nuevas a partir de una expresión evaluada en cada iteración de un `for` que itera sobre alguna secuencia dada.

Efectivamente suelen ser más eficientes que usar `for` + `list.append`, pero la principal razón es que evitan las llamadas reiteradas al método `list.append` usando un bytecode específico (`LIST_APPEND`) para generar la nueva lista.

Por ello , hacer algo como:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
[a.append(i) for i in range(5)]
```

en la infundada idea de que es más rápido que usar un `for` al uso, es una pésima idea, `[a.append(i) for i in range(5)]` nos agrega los elementos deseados a la lista `a`, pero además genera una lista de 5 elementos que son `None`, la salida del método `list.append`, lo cual termina siendo **más ineficiente** y menos legible que usar un `for` "normal".

Por otro lado, el operador lógico `or` simplemente **evalúa** el primer operando y comprueba si es verdadero, si lo es ese operando es el resultado de la operación y el segundo operando ni se evalúa. En caso de que se considere como `False` la evaluación del segundo operando es el resultado del la operación lógica. Si se encadenan varios, simplemente retornaran el primero que sea evaluado como `True` o el último si ninguno lo es.

```
>>> 0 or 5
5
>>> 0 or 3 or 5
3
>>> False or 0 or None # Todos son evaluados como False
None
>>> [4, 1] or [6, 7]
[4, 1]
>>> False or True
True
>>> False or False
False
>>> 4 * 0 or 3 + 2
5
>>> 0 or print("foo")
foo
>>> 5 or print("foo")
5
>>> print("foo") or 5 # print retorna None (False)
foo
5
```

Dicho esto, ¿qué hace por tanto tu código?

```
Lista2 = [Indices.append(indices)  or  Carac.append(carac) for indices,carac in enumerate(Unicode)]
```

Esto simplemente itera sobre el iterador retornado por `enumerate` y por cada pareja de valores evalúa la expresión:

```
Indices.append(indices)  or  Carac.append(carac)
```

y el resultado de evaluar ésto es lo que constituye el item de `Lista2`.

Como se ha visto, esto primero evalúa si la expresión que le precede es verdadera, lo que equivale a ejecutar `Indices.append(indices)`, lo cual añade `indices` a `Indices` y retorna `None`. Dado que `None` en Python se evalúa como `False`, se pasa a comprobar la veracidad del lado derecho del operador `or`, por lo que se ejecuta `Carac.append(carac)` lo cual también retorna `None` y añade `carac` a la lista `Carac`, por lo que lo anterior equivale (desde el punto de vista de la lista por compresión) a :

```
None or None
```

que como cabe esperar es `None`, por lo que terminas con tus dos listas pobladas como quieres y con una lista (`Lista2`) totalmente inútil llenita de "Nones".

La causa de que no funcionara sin el `or`  es porque la expresión:

```
Indices.append(indices)  Carac.append(carac)
```

es sencillamente inválida, mientras que intercalando el `or` tienes una expresión que genera algo al ser evaluada (`None`) y que se usa para poblar la lista.

Dado que quieres una lista con los índices y otra con los elementos sin ningún filtro de por medio, no tiene sentido alguno que uses `enumerate` ni te compliques la vida. Tu lista `caracteristicas` es una simple copia superficial de la lista original:

```
lista = [4, 6, 7, 9]
caracteristicas = list(lista)
indices = list(range(len(caracteristicas)))
```

uso `list()` para generar la copia en vez de `lista[::]` o `lista.copy()` porque de esta forma funciona sobre otros iterables también:

```
cad = "Hola"
caracteristicas = list(cad)
indices = list(range(len(caracteristicas)))
print(indices)
print(caracteristicas)
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
> ['H', 'o', 'l', 'a']
> ```

```
iterador = range(4,15, 2)
caracteristicas = list(iterador)
indices = list(range(len(caracteristicas)))
print(indices)
print(caracteristicas)
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
> ```

Oviamente hay más formas de conseguirlo, puedes obtener lo que deseas usando `zip` también:

```
lista = [4, 6, 7, 9, 8]
indices, caracteristicas = (list(z) for z in zip(*enumerate(lista)))
```

lo cual puede ser útil en algunos casos, por ejemplo para obtener los numero impares y sus indices:

```
lista = [4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5]
indices, impares = (list(z) for z in  zip(*(idx, item)
                                for idx, n in enumerate(lista) if n % 2)))
print(indices)
print(imparares)
```

> ```
> [2, 3, 5]
> [7, 9, 5]
> ```

aunque muy legible no es que sea. La otra alternativa es simplemente usar un `for` "normal", no siempre lo que puedas ganar en tiempo de ejecución compensa lo que pierdes en legibilidad:

```
lista = [4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5]
indices = []
impares = []
for idx, n in enumerate(lista):
    if item % 2:
        indices.append(idx)
        impares.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

EL argumento OR funciona cuando 1 de las 2 preposiciones es verdadero, eso significa que cuando 1 de tus preposiciones se cumple primero imprimira tus indices y luego obtienes una lista con tus elementos porque tu preposicion fue verdadera. Espero haberte ayudado.